# Are there any arithmetic statements where there does not exist a proof proving the statement?

Tags: peano-axioms, incompleteness

Because of Godel's Incompleteness Theorems, there must exist certain statements about the numbers which have no proof via the Peano axioms. This includes [The Strengthened Ramsey Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem).

However, this leads me to wonder if there are any statements in which we know there cannot be a proof showing the statement to be true using the Peano axioms, but there might be a proof showing the statement to be false (i.e. a counterexample), although we haven't found one. Do such statements exist?

Comment: I am also interested in this.